# Firebase RealTime Database search and pagination

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, pagination

I am trying to paginate my search results from a firebase search query but the pagination is returning wrong data.When I make the initial search query, I get the required results but upon scrolling to load more I get the wrong data. The loaded items are not what I searched for. What query will be efficient for my loadMore functionality.

```
 //initial search query
 queryRef = dbUsers.queryOrdered(byChild: "dept").queryStarting(atValue: searchName).queryEnding(atValue: searchName!+"\u{F8FF}").queryLimited(toLast: 20)


 //loadMore query, for pagination upon scrolling to loadMore items
 queryRef = dbUsers.queryOrdered(byChild: "dept").queryStarting(atValue: searchName).queryEnding(atValue: lastValue, childKey: lastKey).queryLimited(toLast: 20)
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the JSON you are querying for a specific `searchName` value (as text, no screenshots)? You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data). Please also show how you process the query results, for example by logging them, and then include the output in your question. To keep the question reasonable when adding this information, you might want to switch to a smaller page size.